# React router <NavLink> with active style doesn't work as I required with root URL

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I used this NavLinks in the main menu. The issue is that when **'/Test/car'** link is clicked **'/Test'** link is also applying the styles.
I believe it's because **'/Test'** suppose to be the root of other links. so it make sense.

But I want **'/Test'** link also to work like other links when applying the active style. So **'/Test'** will get applied the styles only when that **'Home'** link is clicked.
How I get that done (in a reactjs way)?

```
<Route exact path="/TEST" component={Home}></Route>
<Route path="/TEST/car" component={Car}></Route>
<Route path="/TEST/van" component={Van}></Route>
<Route path="/TEST/train" component={Train}></Route>

<NavLink activeStyle={{borderBottom: 'solid 3px #fff', paddingBottom: '1em'}} to="/TEST" onClick={this.closeMenuForMobile.bind(this)} >Home</NavLink>
<NavLink activeStyle={{borderBottom: 'solid 3px #fff', paddingBottom: '1em'}} to="/TEST/car" onClick={this.closeMenuForMobile.bind(this)} >Car</NavLink>
<NavLink activeStyle={{borderBottom: 'solid 3px #fff', paddingBottom: '1em'}} to="/TEST/van"  onClick={this.closeMenuForMobile.bind(this)} >Van</NavLink>
<NavLink activeStyle={{borderBottom: 'solid 3px #fff', paddingBottom: '1em'}} to="/TEST/train" onClick={this.closeMenuForMobile.bind(this)}>Train</NavLink>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just like your path use `exact`

Change this

```
<NavLink activeStyle={{borderBottom: 'solid 3px #fff', paddingBottom: '1em'}} to="/TEST" onClick={this.closeMenuForMobile.bind(this)} >Home</NavLink>
```

To this

```
<NavLink activeStyle={{borderBottom: 'solid 3px #fff', paddingBottom: '1em'}} exact to="/TEST" onClick={this.closeMenuForMobile.bind(this)} >Home</NavLink>
```

Source:
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md#exact-bool