# React Nav Link activeStyle not being applied when url has parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a NavLink header. The user logs in first, then the url has the user email as a url parameter.

The problem is that the activeStyle is not being applied because I think the NavLink `to` url is not matching up. Or I am not using activeStyle right. If I need to have the url parameter, is there a work-around to get activeStyle to work with my NavLinks?

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><NavLink activeStyle={{borderBottom: '3px solid #46b4f0'}} className="Nav_link" to={"/jasper/about" + email}>About</NavLink></li>
    <li><NavLink activeStyle={{borderBottom: '3px solid #46b4f0'}} className="Nav_link" to={"/jasper" + email}>Jasper</NavLink></li>
    <li><NavLink activeStyle={{borderBottom: '3px solid #46b4f0'}} className="Nav_link" to={"/jasper/contact" + email}>Contact</NavLink></li>
    <li><NavLink activeStyle={{borderBottom: '3px solid #46b4f0'}} className="Nav_link" to={"/jasper/search" + email}>Search</NavLink></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <Route path="/jasper/about" component={About} />
  <Route exact path="/jasper" component={Jasper} />
  <Route path="/jasper/contact" component={Contact} />
  <Route path="/jasper/search" component={Search} />
</div>
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45158135/react-router-navlink-with-active-style-doesnt-work-as-i-required-with-root-ur

Comment: @EnmanuelDuran I saw the same thing before I posdted and I've tried adding `exact` but it didn't work.

Comment: Not sure if NavLink supports this natively. A workaround would be to add a class dynamically to each link using your own `isActive` abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an isActive property and use logic for the active state to include the email at the end of the pathname

```
<NavLink
  to="/events/123"
  isActive={(location) => location.pathname === this.props.pathname + email}
>Event 123</NavLink>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. i have been trying to add this logic all morning but i have been having issue. could you elaborate on the logic specifically?

Comment: The isActive property will return true or false, You can pass the isActive function a location object which holds the pathname and a bunch of other properties, that location object should give you properties that you can match up to tell the isActive property to return true when you want it. Check out these two links https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/location.md